# How to send put http request with multiple parameters through JSON

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I have the list of students with `id`, `firstName`, `lastName` and `email`, and I have `put` http method that has two arguments, `id` and `student` which finds the student with given `id` and replace that student whit new one (second parameter).

I have to send that `put` http request as `JSON`, but I don't know how to write that request properly. This is what I tried:

```
{
    "id": 8,
    "firstName": "aaaa",
    "lastName": "aaaa",
    "email": "aaaa"
},
{
"id: 2"
}
```

So the student with `id = 2` should be replaced with the student above. Basically I have trouble making this request with two parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

include the id of the student you want to replace on the url. Something like:

server:port/yourapp/student/2

Use the body only for the data related to the student you want to write in the db.

However, changing an id doesn't seem very restful.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom object model that will hold a `student` and an additional parameter (id of another student):

```
{
    "student":
    {
        "id": 8,
        "firstName": "aaaa",
        "lastName": "aaaa",
        "email": "aaaa"
    },
    "studentId": 2
}
```